# What is the right way to print .dat on Java Console?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

What is the right way to print .dat on Java Console?

```
public void open(){
    try {
        FileInputStream inFile =
            new FileInputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
        //While (in.readLine!=null){
            System.out.print(in.readLine());}
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally{  }
}
```

This gives the result of a single line only and  characters have different size
How to read all data and print onto console with readable output!

when I original write in this dat file, I use

```
FileOutputStream outFile =
    new FileOutputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
out.writeChars(brokerageAcc1.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
String s;
while ((s=br.readline())!=null)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Read more about Reader and Writer from java.io, it helps you to cope with strings input and output

Answer (score 0):

If this is text that you are writing and reading then you should be using the Writer and Reader classes, wrapped with a BufferedWriter and BufferedReader to provide line handling.

```
FileOutputStream outFile =
    new FileOutputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new Writer(outFile));
writer.write(Acc1.toString());
// maybe write a newline??
writer.newLine();
```

Then to read it back it you using a buffered reader:

```
FileInputStream inFile =
    new FileInputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inFile));
while (true) {
    String line = reader.readline();
    if (line == null) break;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If characters have different sizes on your console, then the console itself is configured to display text with a proportional font. This has to be adjusted on the console and can't be controlled from your java application.

You're writing to an `ObjectOutputStream`. This is somewhat strange, but you may have a requirement for this. To read from such a file, use the following code (Note: I slightly changed your writing algorithm! Stream closing and exception handling NOT included)

```
// writing

FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);

String s = brokerageAcc1.toString();
out.writeInt(s.length());
System.out.println(s.length());

out.writeChars(s);

// reading

FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("C:"+File.separatorChar+"transactions.dat");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
int length = in.readInt();     // get the number of chars
System.out.println(""+length);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  result.append(in.readChar());
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Comment: result.append(in.readChar());this line gives exception                                           java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readChar(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readChar(Unknown Source) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readChar(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Jenifer - did you change the "writing" part? I've added two more "debug" lines, please check, that both lines print the same value. EOF shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Jenifer - did one more change - there's a chance, that brokerageAcc1.toString() changes between reading the length and the string. Stored it into a variable.